# Obtener los valores de checkboxes dinámcos

Tags: checkbox

Tengo varios checkboxes dinámicos y necesito saber a cuales se le ha hecho click para luego enviar esos datos a la base de datos. He googleado pero la información que aparece es sobre checkboxes "fijos", si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería mucho.
Acá tienen el código de como hago los checkboxes dinámicos

```
include "models/conexion.php";

$dep_mant_usuarios = $_POST['division'];
$sql_modulo = "SELECT idmodulos, idDivision, nombreModulo FROM modulos WHERE idDivision = '$dep_mant_usuarios' ORDER BY nombreModulo ASC";

$query_modulo = $pdo->prepare($sql_modulo);
$query_modulo->execute();
$result = $query_modulo->fetchAll();

$query_modulo = null;

 echo'<table class="tg">';
    echo'<tr>';
        echo'<th class="tg-xldj modulo">MÓDULOS</th>';
        echo'<th class="tg-c3ow rol">Ingresar</th>';
        echo'<th class="tg-c3ow rol">Modificar</th>';
        echo'<th class="tg-c3ow rol">Consultar</th>';
        echo'<th class="tg-c3ow rol">Imprimir</th>';
        echo'<th class="tg-c3ow rol">Exportar</th>';
    echo'</tr>';

    if (is_array($result)){
        foreach ($result as $row){
            $nom_modulo = $row['nombreModulo'];
            $id_modulo = $row['idmodulos'];

                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td class="tg-hmp3"><input name="" type="checkbox" value="'.$id_modulo.'"> '.$nom_modulo.'</td>';
                    echo '<td class="tg-0lax" ><center><input name="" value="" type="checkbox"></center></td>';
                    echo '<td class="tg-0lax" ><center><input name="" value="" type="checkbox"></center></td>';
                    echo '<td class="tg-0lax" ><center><input name="" value="" type="checkbox"></center></td>';
                    echo '<td class="tg-0lax" ><center><input name="" value="" type="checkbox"></center></td>';
                    echo '<td class="tg-0lax" ><center><input name="" value="" type="checkbox"></center></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
        }
    }

    echo'</table>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando crees tus checkbox agrega en el atributo name  el valor `idModulo[]`. Así sera un array la que guarde los valores de los checkbox que se envia mediante POST

```
echo '<td class="tg-hmp3"><input name="idModulo[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$id_modulo.'"> '.$nom_modulo.'</td>';
```

lo recuperas de POST con

```
$_POST['idModulo'];
```

luego en el código usas un for o un foreach para revisarlos como cualquier arreglo

Comment: Gracias Csharls por la ayuda